# Variable declaration after function's argument list

Tags: c, function, syntax, declaration

I stumpled upon a C code, where variables seem to be declared after the argument list of a function. I did not know that this was possible.

In the code, `int r` and `int *a` are declared right after the argument list of `arr2int`. How does this affect the local variables `a` and `r` of `arr2int`?

The actual reason why I want to understand the code is because if I let it run on my linux x86 `a[1] = 1` at `//MARKER` when `arr2int` ist called the fist time.

But if I let it run ona an ARM-based omap4 dev board `a[1]=0` and I dont know why there is a difference.

Could someone comment on this please?

```
long arr2int(a,r)
int r;
int *a;
{
   int i;
   long mul, result = 0, temp;

   //MARKER
   for (i=1; i<=r; i++) {
      mul = 1;
      temp = a[i]-1;
      while (temp--)
         mul = mul << 1;
      result += mul;
   }
   return(result);
}
```

And the calling method:

```
void generateEncodingTable(){
    register int i,j;
    long temp;
    int seed = 133757;

    printf("\n[I] - Generating Encoding Table\n");
    for (pattern = 0; pattern < 4096; pattern++) {
        temp = pattern << 11;          /* multiply information by X^{11} */
        encoding_table[pattern] = temp + get_syndrome(temp);/* add redundancy */
    }

    decoding_table[0] = 0;
    decoding_table[1] = 1;
    temp = 1; 
    for (i=2; i<= 23; i++) {
        temp *= 2;
        decoding_table[get_syndrome(temp)] = temp;
    }

    a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2;

    temp = arr2int(a,2);
    decoding_table[get_syndrome(temp)] = temp;
    for (i=1; i<253; i++) {
        nextcomb(23,2,a);
        temp = arr2int(a,2);
    decoding_table[get_syndrome(temp)] = temp;
    }

    a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2; a[3] = 3;
    temp = arr2int(a,3);
    decoding_table[get_syndrome(temp)] = temp;
    for (i=1; i<1771; i++) {
        nextcomb(23,3,a);
        temp = arr2int(a,3);
        decoding_table[get_syndrome(temp)] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `a` as used in `generateEncodingTable()`?

Comment: a is declared globally right after #include statements as:

`int a[4];`

Comment: Perhaps the order matters?

Comment: Well I am using exactly the same code (1:1) to be executed on x86 and on the ARM platform and it gives different results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old notation known as K & R (Kernighan & Ritchie, after Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie) Notation for declaring the functions. If your compiler supports it, you can use it and it is same as declaring the function with ANSI notation.

Comment: So what is the deal with `int r; int *a;`? Where do I have to put them to form a 'newer' syntactical version of the code? Ok I got it.

Comment: `int r; int *a;` simply means that parameter `r` is of type `int` and parameter `a` is of type `int*` (pointer to an integer).

Comment: It's still valid syntax as of the 2011 standard; don't want to arbitrarily break all that late-'70s/early-'80s legacy code that's still active out there.

Comment: If it's not too late, to respond to @RichardLaurant , just rewrite `long arr2int(a,r)
int r;
int *a;` (K&R) to `long arr2int(int* a,int r)` (Ansi)

Answer (score 6):

As mention by others, this is an early style of function coding.

Following is a pitfall of that style.  **Be aware there is no type checking on passed parameters.**  It *may* explain your run time differences.

Say you *declare* a function

```
int foo(a,b,c);
```

All the compiler sees at that point is a function named "foo" taking 3 arguments and 
returning an `int`.  Thus usage checking is limited to that.

Let's assume `sizeof(short)` < `sizeof(int)` < `sizeof(long)` and the function is defined as

```
int foo(a,b,c)
  int a;
  long b;
  int c;
{ /* code body */ }
```

Notice the following usage of `foo`

```
int d,e,f;
d = foo(1,2L,3);
e = foo((short)1,2L,3);
f = foo(1,2,3);
```

The first usages works fine, the right size integers are passed to `foo`.
The 2nd usages also works fine.  The first argument is promoted to `int` size before the call, much like `printf("%d", (short)2)` promotes `(short)2` to `int` before passing to `printf()`.
The 3rd is a problem as the compiler does not *know* the second argument needs to be `long`.  Thus the data passed to `foo` is not passed correctly. --> UB

Answer (score 2):

This is an old C syntax. If your compiler can swallow it then it should work the same as if you have declared the functions the normal, ANSI way.

Answer (score 2):

This is K&R C, i.e, the C language described by the first edition of *The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. The second edition has turned to ANSI C(C89).

You shoul always use ANSI C style:

[Rationale for International Standard - Programming Languages C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) 6.11.6 Function declarators

> The characterization as obsolescent of the use ofthe “old style” function declarations and 
>   definitions, that is, the traditional style not using prototypes, signals the Committee’s intent that the new prototype style should eventually replace the old style.
>
> The gist of this case is that the new syntax addresses some of the most glaring weaknesses of the language defined in K&R, that the new style is superior to the old style on every count.

Answer (score 0):

**It is just a way of declaring types of function parameters:**

```cpp
void func (first_param, second_param)
int first_param;
int second_param;
{
 // ...
}
```

is equal to

```cpp
void func (int first_param, int second_param)
{
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Not really equal as mentioned in other responses.